# Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "rook-cephfs": rpc error: code = Aborted desc = an operation with the given Volume ID pvc- already exists

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rook-storage, kubernetes-rook

I am deploying application with helm chart.
I am facing an issue with StorageClass rook-ceph whenever I deploy a chart my pods are in pending state because pvc are not getting created. Logs for pvc are

```
Warning  ProvisioningFailed    96s (x13 over 20m)    rook-ceph.cephfs.csi.ceph.com_csi-cephfsplugin-provisioner-775dcbbc86-nt8tr_170456b2-6876-4a49-9077-05cd2395cfed  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "rook-cephfs": rpc error: code = Aborted desc = an operation with the given Volume ID pvc-f65acb47-f145-449e-ba1c-e8a61efa67b0 already exists
```

Comment: https://github.com/rook/rook/issues/4896

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster (your config file)? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to restart MDS service, if you can copy the data of pvc to a new one, it should work also